# session lost after redirect php

Tags: php, session

first of all, I found several other questions, but nothing helped me so far.
Quick question: I lose my session-variables after a redirect. Check this:

**Login.php**

```
if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}/im", $_POST["foo"])) {
    if($_POST["email"]) {
        $aPieces = explode("@", $_POST["email"]);
        if(in_array($aPieces[1], $aAllowedMails)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["isAllowed"] = true;
            header("Location: start.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

**Start.php**

```
<?php
    // session_start()
    if($_SESSION["isAllowed"] == true) : 
?>
some content

<?php else : ?>

<h1>Acces Denied</h1>

<?php endif ?>
```

my session is always NULL on the 2nd page (start.php), which leads to the "access denied"-text. Tried to add the 2nd `session_start` as well on `start.php`, but that ends up with the error-message:

> session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent >
>   (output started at [path]/start.php:1) in 
>   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you start the session on the next page? 
If you don't, you can do this by adding this to your code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    if($_SESSION["isAllowed"] == true) : 
?>
some content

<?php else : ?>

<h1>Acces Denied</h1>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: tried that, but that leads to the error:
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/web629/html/personal/sgbdd/start.php:1) in

Comment: @DasSaffe you need to be sure that you start your session before you do anything else, so preferably at the top of your code.

Comment: it basically starts with session_start - check updated question please

Comment: @DasSaffe are you sure that there is not any other output before your session starts? Like errors? Try my new code.

Comment: FFS! you're right... it was a BOM. thank you.
Accept asap. thank you